# Having a problem finding the sum by iterating through args

Tags: python

noob here, sorry if this sounds like a dumb and obvious question, I'm currently doing a tutorial and I'm in the args section of the tutorial and for some reason it fails to iterate through the tuple in order to sum up the numbers as it keeps on displaying only the value of the first index, I don't know what I'm doing wrong, please help, I'm using Pycharm and version 3.11.1 of python if that has anything to do with it

```
def add (*numbersum):
    sum = 0
    for i in numbersum:
        sum += i
        return sum


print(add(0,559,499,2))
```

I went back to the tutorial to double check and for some reason it just doesn't work for me, it's supposed to give me the sum of all arguments but it isn't

Comment: Answer below shows your issue. I suggest you try writing/pasting code in [link](https://pythontutor.com/python-debugger.html#mode=edit) and using Visualize Execution to step through such short code sections and watch what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the "return sum" is double indented.
Try to un-indent it once

Comment: yeah that was the problem, thank you sm!

Answer (score 1):

Mind that `sum` is a [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html). You should avoid using the same namespace.

```
def add(*numbers):
    result = 0
    for n in numbers:
        result += n
    return result
```

Using the built-in `sum`:

```
def add(*numbers):
    return sum(numbers)
```

So, in practice, better to use `sum` directly with `sum([0,559,499,2])`

Comment: This was very much helpful, thanks for the info!

Answer (score 0):

The bug in the given code is due to the placement of the `return sum` statement inside the `for` loop, where it should be placed outside.

Function mistakenly returns the sum of only the first number in the `numbersum` argument. To rectify this issue, the `return sum` statement needs to be moved outside the loop, allowing the function to accurately calculate and return the total sum of all the numbers

```
def add(*numbersum):
    sum = 0
    for i in numbersum:
        print(i)
        sum += i
    return sum

print(add(0,559,499,2))
```

Comment: just tried it, thank you so much